# How to cancel fetching/downloading big messages/folders in mutt?

Tags: mutt, neomutt

How can I cancel the download of big messages or folders in Mutt?

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does nothing and I tried different things and keys and searched the web for

> how to cancel ...

I don't want to quit the program, I just want to interrupt the fetching of files (e.g. a 15MB file or a folder with 2000 messages) before it reaches 100%.

Have I overlooked something?